# Find the second degree polynomial such that P(-1) = 132, P(0) = 98, P(1) = 88

Tags: polynomials

How are you able to find a second degree polynomial based on only knowing three values of the polynomial like in the title? P(-1) = 132, P(0) = 98, P(1) = 88

Comment: Write down a general polynomial of second degree, insert the values, and solve the resulting system of equations.

Comment: Consider the general quadratic: $ax^2 + bx + c$. You get three equations in three unknowns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using that $P(x)$ has the form $$P(x)=ax^2+bx+c$$ then we get
$$P(-1)=a-b+c=132$$
$$P(0)=c=98$$
$$P(1)=a+b+c=88$$
for your Control: $$a=12,b=-22,c=98$$

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to solve the system:

$$\begin{cases}
a-b+c=132 \\
c=98 \\
a+b+c=88
\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}
a=12\\
b=-22 \\
c=98
\end{cases}$$

So the polynomial is $12x^2-22x+98$